# How do I run GraphQL queries after router.query?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

Started learning React and Next just some time ago and having trouble making this work.
Also tried using useLazyQuery but could not figure out how to return properly.

```
...
const TaskSingle = () => {

    const { category } = router.query;

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_TASKS, {
        variables: {
            taskFilter: {
                taskCategory: 5, // works
                // taskCategory: category // doesn't work
            },
        },
    });
}

const { categories } = data;

return (
  <div>
  {categories.map((cat) => {
      <div key={cat.id}>
          {cat.name}
      </div>
  })}
 </div>
)
```

When I try to use "category" instead of a number I'm getting this error:
http://hidden-url:3000/graphql:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: What library is `useQuery` and `useLazyQuery` coming from? Is it Apollo?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, apollo/client

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you get any error? If so, could you post that too?

Comment: Uhm I might have figured out this one.
"category" is a string and I needed a number

Comment: Used const category = Number(router.query.category); instead of const { category} = router.query and it's working ...

Comment: Makes sense. Don't forget to add the solution as the answer if that worked, to help future people who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used

`const category = Number(router.query.category);`

instead of

`const { category} = router.query;`

because I needed a number and not a string.